# highlight breakpoints with pdb

Tags: python, gud, realgud

I use pdb with gud to debug python scripts. I am just wondering if there is way to highlight the lines with breakpoints? For example, in some screenshots of gud-gdb, some people seem to have red circles to the left of lines with breakpoints. How to achieve that with pdb? And is there a way to list all breakpoints (like the breakpoints buffer of gud-gdb)?

I actually tried realgud once, and it did have this feature. However, realgud is lacking documentation, and I find it extremely confusing to use. I have very limited knowledge of elisp, so I cannot figure out what is going on without a more detailed guide.

By the way, why gud with pdb does not have the function gud-until?

Thanks.

Comment: You might like to `M-x report-emacs-bug` and request this feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, realgud is lacking documentation,

Although I largely agree, there is a wiki [How-to-Use](https://github.com/realgud/realgud/wiki/How-to-Use) which anyone can contribute to. And I suppose you can open an [issue](https://github.com/realgud/realgud/issues) to get help.

> By the way, why gud with pdb does not have the function gud-until?

pdb does have an *until* command. Although when I tried it outside of a function it seemed to not work, I suppose there's no reason not it couldn't be included in gud. A guess is that it's not there because *until* was a more recent addition to gdb and thus gud.

So https://gist.github.com/rocky/7d773de32be146eb7292 has a simple patch that you might be able to apply to gud.el . If you haven't already reported the emacs bug, you can attach this as a suggested remedy. (And if you have reported it I suppose you can still attach it if this hasn't been already addressed.)

Comment: Thanks. I've been getting used to pdb with gud and it does the job. Realgud looks a lot more powerful, but when I tried it there were several things got me very confused. It was quite a while ago, so I don't remember clearly, but I seem to recall that I wasn't able to clear the breakpoints (the red circles).

Comment: It was probably a bug. So next time file an issue or look to see if someone else has filed one first. Just as you need help, projects like this also need help. And that can be something as simple as reporting what you see.